# How to set css attribute for pseudo element in Dart

Tags: css, dart, pseudo-element

I need to overwrite the css attribute of a pseudo element in Dart.

In Javascript, there is the option to this via e.g.

```
document.getOverrideStyle(p, ':after').display = 'none';
```

In Dart I only found readonly access, e.g.

```
List<CssRule> rules = window.getMatchedCssRules(myElement, ':before');
```

or

```
 CssStyleDeclaration css = myElement.getComputedStyle('::before');
```

Any chance to override pseudo element css attributes in Dart??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the `List<CssRule>` you get back from

```
List<CssRule> rules = window.getMatchedCssRules(myElement, ':before');

(rules[0] as CssStyleRule).style.display = 'none';
```

You might need to search the rules if there is more than one to change the right one.

Try it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/aa9632a331eebdf1fa36)

Comment: Thanks - but I get "The getter 'style' is not defined for the class 'CssRule'": - see https://dartpad.dartlang.org/a6e504f829decfe94876

Comment: Sorry, I tried it only in the debugger which didn't complain. I updated my answer.

Comment: ... getting there - but it still shows and I get the error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null" also in your DartPad

Comment: I missed to check the console output. The problem is that `getMatchedCssRules()` returns null in the DartPad. Still investigating.

Comment: ... in the real apps, the code does not fail, but it updates the style of the element itself, not the pseudo element .. ???

Comment: ... works in the real apps - the rules[0] (in my case) returned "*, ::before, ::after {}" in cssText - the second one was the "real one" - so you have to search for the right rule :-/

Comment: Seems `getMatchedCssRules()` might get removed (with no replacement), I wonder why they haven't yet. The discussion was in January https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/fd-QLCiLESQ/_mfowSsRR8oJ, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=438278

Comment: an additional drawback is that it changes the css rule itself - not the instance attribute :-(